# Find the probability function of random variable Y

Tags: probability, statistics

Two balls are drawn at random form a box containing ten balls numbered 0,1,...9.Let random variable Y be their total.
Tabulate the probability function of Y if the sampling is without replacement.
I dont know how to solve this question.Please help.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{10}{2}=45$ equally likely pairs of numbers.

The sum $Y$ must be $\ge 1$ and $\le 17$. For each value of $k$, where $1\le k\le 17$, we need to compute $\Pr(Y=k)$.

We do a couple of calculations, and let you deal with the rest.

Let $k=1$. Our sum is $1$ precisely if we picked the numbers $0$ and $1$. Thus $\Pr(Y=1)=\frac{1}{45}$.

Let $k=5$. Our sum is $5$ if we picked the numbers $0$ and $5$, or $1$ and $4$, or $2$ and $3$. Each of these has probability $\frac{1}{45}$, so $\Pr(Y=5)=\frac{3}{45}$.

Deal separately with the possibilities $k=1$ to $17$. When you are finished, check that your numbers add up to $1$. Symmetry will help shorten the calculations.

Comment: You are welcome. I have left a fair amount of work for you to do, but now that you know how to attack it, there should be no difficulty.